# Does packing a structure affect sub-structures?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015

We recently found some code submitted to our codebase, along the following lines:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct xyzzy {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER header;
    char plugh;
    long twisty;
} myVar;
```

My question is: does the packing apply *only* to the immediate structure or might it affect the packing of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` as well. I can't see the latter case being very useful since it would make the structure different to what you would get from the Windows API calls, for example. Case in point, let's assume the structure is:

```
typedef struct {
    char aChar;
    DWORD biSize;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

That structure would be vastly different with a packing of one rather than the default eight for Windows (32-bit anyway, may be sixteen for 64-bit).

Is the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` "protected" from the packing by virtue of the fact it's almost certainly be declared earlier? If it was declared as part of the outer declaration, would it be subject to the packing then?

Comment: Fortunately the case in point shouldn't be a problem anyway, as the "real" `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is already "perfectly" packed. But I see the point and it's an interesting question, +1.

Comment: @Yunnosch: the standard doesn't know a thing about `#pragma pack`, so we are left with vendor-specific documentation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, that is what I intended to imply. Still, referring to at least one specified tool chain and its documentation would make a (tool specific) decent answer.

Comment: A Win32 application should not declare BITMAPINFOHEADER, it is [provided by Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx). We'll have to assume it is correctly packed.

Comment: To avoid such problems the headers declarations are crafted in such a way to keep the correct variables layout whichever packing will be applied. Have a look inside Win or *nix headers and you'll find a lot of padding variables to keep layout alignment. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485168/is-struct-packing-deterministic/44486156#44486156 ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx):

> `pack` takes effect at the first `struct`, `union`, or `class` declaration after the pragma is seen. `pack` has no effect on definitions.

`header` is a member definition, so it isn't affected.

> it was declared as part of the outer declaration, would it be subject to the packing then?

Yes, as it would be a `struct` declaration.

Also, as *Lightness Races in Orbit* remarks in a comment, a more convincing wording can be found immediately before:

> > To pack a class is to place its members directly after each other in memory.
>
> i.e. it says nothing about what those members themselves contain, which may be data and/or padding. The fact that (as explored above) packedness is attached to a type would seem to reinforce that

---

Still, the documentation is vague enough, so it's best to test that this interpretation is correct; [both gcc](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:___c,source:%27struct+Foo+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++int+i%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Bar_Unpacked+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23pragma+pack(push,+1)%0Astruct+Bar_Packed+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Bar_PackedPacked+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo_Packed+%7B%0A++++++++char+c%3B%0A++++++++int+i%3B%0A++++%7D+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%23pragma+pack(pop)%0A%0Aint+*u_u(struct+Bar_Unpacked+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+*p_u(struct+Bar_Packed+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+*p_p(struct+Bar_PackedPacked+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.182846371347786,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg72,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%270%27),lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-m32%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.08114379571297,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2%27,t:%270%27)),k:15.736009832939242,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and [VC++](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27struct+Foo+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++int+i%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Bar_Unpacked+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23pragma+pack(push,+1)%0Astruct+Bar_Packed+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Bar_PackedPacked+%7B%0A++++char+c%3B%0A++++struct+Foo_Packed+%7B%0A++++++++char+c%3B%0A++++++++int+i%3B%0A++++%7D+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%23pragma+pack(pop)%0A%0Aint+*u_u(struct+Bar_Unpacked+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+*p_u(struct+Bar_Packed+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+*p_p(struct+Bar_PackedPacked+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+%26b-%3Ef.i%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.182846371347786,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_32,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%270%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:/O2,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.08114379571297,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW%27,t:%270%27)),k:15.736009832939242,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) behave as expected. Not that I'm particularly surprised - anything different would break havoc in the type system (taking a pointer to a member of a packed structure would actually provide a pointer to something different than its type says<sup>1</sup>).

The general idea is: once you finish defining a `struct`, its binary layout is fixed, and any of its instantiations will conform to it, including subobjects of packed structures. The current `#pragma pack` value is considered only when defining new structures, and when doing so the binary layout of the members is a fixed black box.

---

***Notes***

1. To be honest, this is a bit of an x86-centric view; machines with stronger alignment requirements would object that even pointers to layout-correct but misaligned structures aren't kosher: although the offsets of fields relative to the given pointer are correct, they aren't really pointers that can be used as they are.

   OTOH, given a pointer to an unaligned object you can always detect that it's unaligned and `memcpy` it to a correctly-aligned location, so it's not as bad as a hypothetical pointer to a packed object, whose layout is effectively unknown unless you happen to know the packing of its parent.

Comment: _"`header` is a member definition, so it isn't affected."_ I'm not entirely convinced by this rationale. Clearly `xyzzy` itself is also a definition - there is something dodgy about the MSDN wording (go figure). I suspect what it _really_ means is that you can't apply `__attribute__((__packed__))` to the definition of an instance of type `xyzzy` and expect it to be packed, if the definition of `xyzzy` itself wasn't already.

Comment: Personally I think the only "proof" (other than the testing you've done) is this wording: _"To pack a class is to place its members directly after each other in memory"_. i.e. it says nothing about what those members themselves contain, which may be data and/or padding. The fact that (as explored above) packedness is attached to a _type_ would seem to reinforce that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with both considerations, although the way I see it the definition thing is meant to apply both to members and actual variable definitions (e.g. globals or even locals defined while the `#pragma` is active). That being said, your quotation and its interpretation is quite significant as well, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

From what I have seen, it only applies to immediate structure.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct /*__attribute__((__packed__))*/ struct_Inner {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) struct_Outer {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
    struct struct_Inner stInner;
};

int main() 
{
   struct struct_Inner oInner;
   struct struct_Outer oOuter;
   printf("\n%zu Bytes", sizeof(oInner));
   printf("\n%zu Bytes", sizeof(oOuter));
}
```

Prints:

```
12 Bytes
18 Bytes
```

When I pack the `struct_Inner` it prints:

```
6 Bytes
12 Bytes
```

This is when using GCC 7.2.0.

Again, this is not specific to C standard by any means (I just had to read), its more to do with what compilers do.

> Is the BITMAPINFOHEADER "protected" from the packing by virtue of the fact it's almost certainly be declared earlier?

I guess yes. It would entirely depend upon the way `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is declared.

Comment: Don't worry, providing tool-specific "observations from the wild" (with adequate statement of tool name and version) is considered here at StackOverflow to be adequate participation in the answering process.

Comment: @Yunnosch Considering the question involves `#pragma ...`, I'd say a tool-specific answer is all that's *possible*.

Comment: This is irrelevant to a question about MSVC.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming GCC (or Clang emulating GCC), you can find some relevant information at [Structure Layout Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas), where it says that the presence of the `push` preserves the current packing state on a stack of states:

> For compatibility with Microsoft Windows compilers, GCC supports a set of `#pragma` directives that change the maximum alignment of members of structures (other than zero-width bit-fields), unions, and classes subsequently defined. The *n* value below always is required to be a small power of two and specifies the new alignment in bytes.
>
> 1. `#pragma pack(n)` simply sets the new alignment.
> 2. `#pragma pack()` sets the alignment to the one that was in effect when compilation started (see also command-line option `-fpack-struct[=n]` see [Code Gen Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)).
> 3. `#pragma pack(push[,n])` pushes the current alignment setting on an internal stack and then optionally sets the new alignment.
> 4. `#pragma pack(pop)` restores the alignment setting to the one saved at the top of the internal stack (and removes that stack entry). Note that `#pragma pack([n])` does not influence this internal stack; thus it is possible to have `#pragma pack(push)` followed by multiple `#pragma pack(n)` instances and finalized by a single `#pragma pack(pop)`.

Thus, the `#pragma` in the code added affects all subsequent structure definitions too, until countermanded by `#pragma pack(pop)`.  I'd be worried about that.

The documentation doesn't say what happens if you do `#pragma pack(pop)` when there is no state on the internal stack.  Most likely, it falls back to the setting when compilation started.

Answer (score 6):

According to [GCC reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.0/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

> In the following example `struct my_packed_struct`'s members are
>   packed closely together, **but the internal layout of its s member is
>   not packed** - to do that, `struct my_unpacked_struct` would need to
>   be packed too.
>
> ```
>   struct my_unpacked_struct
>    {
>       char c;
>       int i;
>    };
>
>   struct my_packed_struct __attribute__ ((__packed__))
>     {
>        char c;
>        int  i;
>        struct my_unpacked_struct s;
>     };
> ```
>
> You may only specify this attribute on the definition of a enum, struct or union, not on a typedef which does not also define the
>   enumerated type, structure or union.

Comment: TBH this is a correct answer *for gcc* and for its `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`, OP actually asked about `#pragma pack` on VC++ 2015. Of course I expect it to be the same (hence the upvote), but given that we are talking about compiler-specific behavior and non-standard extensions I'd expect an answer to tackle the specifics of OP's environment.

Comment: It must be like this so that it's possible to obtain a pointer to the nested struct and receive the same data layout as any other pointer of that type.

Comment: Why are you citing GCC reference to answer a question about MSVC?

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer the question, but might offer an idea why existing compilers decided not to pack sub-structs, and why future compilers are unlikely to change that.

A packing that transitively affected sub-structures would break the type system in subtle ways.

Consider:

```
//Header A.h
typedef struct {
    char aChar;
    DWORD biSize;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;


// File A.c
#include <A.h>

void doStuffToHeader(BITMAPINFOHEADER* h)
{
    // compute stuff based on data stored in h
    // ...
}


// File B.c
#include <A.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct xyzzy {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER header;
    char plugh;
    long twisty;
} myVar;

void foo()
{
    doStuffToHeader(&myVar.header);
}
```

I pass a pointer to a packed struct to a function that is not aware of the packing. Any attempts by the function to read or write data from the struct will easily break in horrible ways. If a compiler deems this unacceptable, it has two possibilities for fixing the problem:

- Transparently unpack the sub-struct into a temporary for the function call and re-pack the result later.
- Internally change the type of the header field in `xyzzy` to something that indicates that it's now a packed type and incompatible with normal `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.

Both of these are obviously problematic. With this reasoning, even if I wanted to write a compiler that supported packing of sub-structs, I would run into numerous follow-up problems. I'd expect my users to start questioning my design decisions in this regard very soon.